# ionic angular view is not getting refreshed with new data

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4, capacitor

i am getting some data after sometime, which i want to merge/replace to the data received before but its not working.
Here how i am replacing original result data.

```
result: Observable<SmsResponse>;
 constructor() {
    this.result = Plugins.SmsaccessPlugin.getAllSms({ value: "inbox"});
  }

  @HostListener("document:myCustomEvent", ["$event"])
  on(event: any) {
    var msg:Observable<SmsResponse> = of(event);
    this.result=msg;//<--- here, but template not showing this new data
  }
```

On html template its used with async pipe `(result | async)`.
(or is there any way to get data from capacitor? )

Answer (score 0):

Try forcing the angular change detection using [NgZone](https://angular.io/api/core/NgZone#run)

```
constructor(private zone: NgZone) {
   this.result = Plugins.SmsaccessPlugin.getAllSms({ value: "inbox"});
});

this.zone.run(() => {
  ...
  this.result = msg;
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

add an *ngIf="result" to the parent dom element
and then {{result | async}}

btw. is your customEvent really firing??